# How to index name of an element in xml column in Postgres

Tags: sql, xml, postgresql

I am trying to index name of elements and I keep running into this error

```
ERROR: set-returning functions are not allowed in index expressions
```

This is what I have tried so far.

Sample xml:

```
<book><title>Manual</title><chapter>1</chapter></book>
```

DDL:

```
CREATE INDEX test2_element_name_idx
ON test2 USING GIN(xpath('local-name(/*)',unnest(xpath('//book/*', xml_data))));
```

Is it possible to index on element names? At the end I want to index on all elements that are under `<book>` (i.e `<title> <chapter>`)

One of the sample usecase is, I wanna query (with xpath) to learn how many books have title. And I believe that indexing it would make the queries more efficient. Please correct me if I my understanding is incorrect.

Comment: You can not index a function call that returns multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

A stated by [a_horse_with_no_name](https://stackoverflow.com/users/330315/a-horse-with-no-name), you can't use a function which returns multiple rows for indexing a table. What you can do instead is to build an array with the multiple rows returned by your function. I propose here after a solution that may need to be adjusted because I never used the xml data type and functions (json is better :-) :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION xml_data_agg(xml_data xml)
RETURNS xml[] LANGUAGE sql AS
$$
  SELECT array(SELECT xpath('local-name(/*)',unnest(xpath('//book/*', xml_data)))) ;
$$ ;

CREATE INDEX test2_element_name_idx
ON test2 USING GIN(xml_data_agg(xml_data));
```

Then you can use this index in queries where you can put this type of where clause : `WHERE xml_data_agg(xml_data) @> array[list_of_the_xlm_elements_to_be_searched]`